# How can I retrieve the maximum value of a MySQL primary key in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, max

I'm working on this code but it ain't working. I've put another query which is working but not this one. Help will be much appreciated.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con1 = null;
    con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itcomplaintsystem", "root", "colbiecaillat");
    Statement stmt = con1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM complaints");

    if(rs != null)
    {         
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String cno=rs.getString("C_NO");
            out.println(cno);
        }
    }

    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    con1.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query

```
SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM complaints
```

you are not assigning an alias to the result. These functions usually return random or default column names, so when you perform

```
String cno=rs.getString("C_NO");
```

the `C_NO` column does not exist on the result set.

To fix it, fix your query like this

```
SELECT MAX(PHONE) as C_NO FROM complaints
```

With `as C_NO` I am giving this column the alias name you are trying to get.

Comment: I just did what you said. The web page isn't displaying anything like before. Why is it so?

Comment: If you execute the query directly on your database, do you get any results?

Comment: Yeah, the query is working fine in my database. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your select part of the query does not have C_NO , If you need max phone then your query will be:

```
SELECT MAX(PHONE) as max_phone FROM complaints
```

assuming that phone is long your complete code will be :

```
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con1 = null;
con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itcomplaintsystem", "root", "colbiecaillat");
Statement stmt = con1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(PHONE) as max_phone FROM complaints");

if(rs != null)
{         
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Long cno=rs.getLong("max_phone");
        out.println(cno);
    }
}

stmt.close();
rs.close();
con1.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I just did what you said. The web page isn't displaying anything like before. Why is it so?

Comment: what is the data type of phone ?

Comment: It got resolved. Please, have a look at an an another problem I'm facing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851632/i-am-trying-to-get-checked-values-from-a-form-contained-in-a-servlet-to-another